# Paste x-flipped pose is all jacked up

Tags: animation, bones

[image]

Whenever I try to paste the x flipped pose it gives me a completely distorted pose.

The names are flipped (.R on right and .L on left)

Comment: I expect the bones (in edit mode) are offset from the armatures origin.

Comment: This does indeed fix the "sunken" thing, however the legs still glitch back like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your .gif doesn't look like it, but if you are following the following procedure:

1. Select bones
2. Copy pose
3. Paste x-flipped pose

Then, you may have a whole mess of mismatched rolls, so:

1. Select armature and switch to edit mode
2. Select all bones
3. Press alt-R to clear roll, or select from the menu Armature/Bone Roll/Clear Roll